# Cannot read property 'sumo' of undefined

Tags: sumoselect.js

I have a sumoselect field with active multiple choices. The input is correctly loaded and it works. I have a problem with methods. I get the undefined error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sumo' of undefined`.

For example this works 
`$('.js-selectsumo-filter').SumoSelect();` 
and this returns the error 
`$('js-selectsumo-filter')[0].sumo.unload();`.

Sumoselect.js is first initialized and afterwards I call my custom js file. I am using jQuery 3.3.1.

```
$('.js-selectsumo-filter').SumoSelect({
             placeholder: placeholder,
             csvDispCount: 5,
             selectAll: false,
             search: true
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution how to call a method without click function as shown in the documentation.

```
$('.your-class-or-id').SumoSelect().sumo.selectItem('test');
```

selectItem can be exchanged for any other method available.